# draw boxplot for data in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1000*8 dataset and each column represent the price of a stock in different time so there are 8 stocks. I want to draw 8 boxplots for all the stocks to examine the extreme values in a loop in python. Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As a quick alternative to using matplotlib directly, Pandas has a reasonable boxplot function that could be used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 8), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df.boxplot(column = list(df.columns))
```

[image: output]

edit: Just realise your question asked to do this in a loop.

```
for c in df.columns:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = df.boxplot(column = c)
```